# Add multiple tilesets of same area to same style in mapbox

Tags: javascript, java, python, mapbox

I am working on a project to show variation in NDVI values of a district in India on a fortnightly basis on Mapbox. For that I need to overlay a layer of tileset showing NDVI values of that district upon a map of India. The problem is that I have to do it for a couple of tilesets (Around 50) of the same district. One way is to use different styles for different tilesets. But it is limited to 20 styles for a free account. Other way is to use same style and overlay the different layers of 'NDVI maps' one upon other. But in that case I'm only able to see the topmost layer. Rest of the layers of same district are not visible. I see that there are two possible solutions.

1. Find a method to put/show a particular layer on top at a time. Rest of the layers would be below the current layer, hence would not be visible.
2. Find a method to automate the addition of a tileset to a style and reset the style (means delete or hide the previous added layer) and add a new layer and show it.

Please help. If the question is not clear, please inform.